# Node.js deprecated object-keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, windows-7-x64

I'm a beginer at node.js, and I'm learning it through a tutorial. I installed node correctly and tested it out with simple console.log calls. The problem is I'm getting an error when trying to run this command:

```
npm-install node-dev -g
```

I get an error:

> "npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object keys"

I'm running node on windows 7 64-bit

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you install have `object-keys` library with version `0.2.0` somewhere in dependency tree, and version `0.2.0` is deprecated.

You have nothing to worry about at the moment, especially as you are just starting to work with node.js, it is only deprecated, and library owner will probably update it soon. However you can help him with that by filing a bug report.

Comment: where do I fill a bug report?

Comment: @gogo_rulez I suppose here: [https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) is the main repository of this library.